# Unit test code that interacts with database without creating data in database

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I want to test my C# code in Visual Studio with unit tests.
The code interacts with a MySQL database.

**An example of what I want to test**
A user opens my application and will be saved in the database via a webservice. Now I want to know if the table `Users` has one more row before the new user came. But if I test the method in the webservice, which will create a record in the database, test data will be in the database. And I don't want test data in my database.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: If it interacts with web services and databases, then it is not a unit test. A unit test tests code _in isolation_.

Comment: use an in-memory database for these sort of integration tests

Comment: you should replace your Database with a dummy and assert against it, as John wrote a UnitTest should not interact with a database at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [mocking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30381/Introduction-to-Mocking). This allows you to simulate your data access code in order to test your business logic.

There are lots of good frameworks out there including [moq](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://code.google.com/p/moq/&ei=3B1aU_CvA6af7Abv0ICAAw&usg=AFQjCNGPuBDNzJG8IH2js8BzSQDGt96Jdw&sig2=7E1PuVwvtpqlcDHSZHmXUg&bvm=bv.65397613,d.ZGU) and [rhino mocks](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks&ei=7x1aU6zLBo2h7AaWqICoBQ&usg=AFQjCNE93TdXOWJNXhVMbuBkdm0nrLuWEA&sig2=LPGtM5TNU118imHLhvCLEw&bvm=bv.65397613,d.ZGU).

If you want to actually populate your database in order to test your data access layer then you're looking for more of an integration test. I've written quite a thorough answer covering my approach to db integration tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690877/how-are-people-unit-testing-with-entity-framework-6-should-you-bother/22691703#22691703).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Mock. For example Moq for C#.

Wrap your database logic in an interface and mock it in your unit test. That way you can interact with the mocked database logic, without really executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is a good way to do it.

It you want more integration test-like approach (which can be helpful when you want to test actual database interaction), you can use a local running MySql server instance.

I've created a project that let you run tests on a live MySql server without setting it up.

You can download it a Nuget package (Mysql.Server) or check it out here: https://github.com/stumpdk/MySql.Server

Answer (score 1):

You can also look for Microsoft fakes framework.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2017