# Problems with wrapping static type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Currently I am developing application which is using 3-rd party static type with a lot of static methods.

E.g.

```
public static class A {
    public static void M() {
   //some actions
   }
}
```

For testing purposes (to provide a posibillity of creating dynamic mocks) I am wrapping this static type as an non-static type with instance methods.

```
public class WrappedA : InterfaceForTesingNeeds {
    public void WrappedM() {
    A.M();
    }
}

public interface InterfaceForTesingNeeds {
    void WrappedM();
}
```

Now I am faced with problem that an amount of methods in `A` is too significant to perform manual wrapping of each of this methods. Can any one provide some way how can I perform something like "automatic wrapping" of static type into non-static?

Comment: Why do you want to wrap these methods? There is, as you say, a lot of cost for no benefit. Just use Fakes. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095050/how-to-test-a-method-that-queries-a-database-without-actually-performing-the-que/26095241#26095241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mocking frameworks require you to change the architecture of your solution, creating and implementing interfaces, and loading implementations dynamically.

However, you can also use Microsoft Fakes, which requires no changes to your application. Fakes come with Visual Studio, so you don't need to download or install anything.

For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

> Microsoft Fakes help you isolate the code you are testing by replacing other parts of the application with stubs or shims. These are small pieces of code that are under the control of your tests.

Using Fakes means that you don't have to spend the time writing and maintaining useless wrapping code, and your computer does not have to spend the time executing it. What is the fasted way to write these wrapper classes? Not writing them!