# Writing integration tests against EF Core and a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

**Working sample at the end of this article (I kept all things I tried [reason for long article], so that others could benefit from it later)**

I am trying to write integration tests for my EF Core 3.1 class library. As unit test framework, I have used XUnit and followed guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases

Here is how the setup looks like (it's a bit longer because I am actually creating a database in my SQL Server in case I need to see the real result from tests output):

```
 public class SharedDatabaseFixture : IDisposable
 {
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();
        private static bool _databaseInitialized;
        private static string _DatabaseName = "Database.Server.Local";
        private static IConfigurationRoot config;

        public SharedDatabaseFixture()
        {
            config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
               .Build();

            var test = config.GetValue<string>("DataSource");

            var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = config.GetValue<string>("DataSource"),
                InitialCatalog = _DatabaseName,
                IntegratedSecurity = true,
            };

            var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            CreateEmptyDatabaseAndSeedData();
            Connection.Open();
        }

        public bool ShouldSeedActualData { get; set; } = true;
        public DbConnection Connection { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext(DbTransaction transaction = null)
        {
            var identity = new GenericIdentity("admin@sample.com", "Admin");
            var contextUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); //add claims as needed
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { User = contextUser };
            var defaultHttpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
            defaultHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext = httpContext;

            var context = new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>().UseSqlServer(Connection).Options, null, defaultHttpContextAccessor);

            if (transaction != null)
            {
                context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
            }
           
            return context;
        }

        private static void ExecuteSqlCommand(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder, string commandText)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = commandText;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder Master => new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = config.GetValue<string>("DataSource"),
            InitialCatalog = "master",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };

        private static string Filename => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SharedDatabaseFixture).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location), $"{_DatabaseName}.mdf");
        private static string LogFilename => Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(SharedDatabaseFixture).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location), $"{_DatabaseName}_log.ldf");

        private static void CreateDatabaseRawSQL()
        {
            ExecuteSqlCommand(Master, $@"IF(db_id(N'{_DatabaseName}') IS NULL) BEGIN CREATE DATABASE [{_DatabaseName}] ON (NAME = '{_DatabaseName}', FILENAME = '{Filename}') END");
        }

        private static List<T> ExecuteSqlQuery<T>(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder, string queryText, Func<SqlDataReader, T> read)
        {
            var result = new List<T>();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = queryText;

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            result.Add(read(reader));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static void DestroyDatabaseRawSQL()
        {
            var fileNames = ExecuteSqlQuery(Master, $@"SELECT [physical_name] FROM [sys].[master_files] WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID('{_DatabaseName}')", row => (string)row["physical_name"]);

            if (fileNames.Any())
            {
                ExecuteSqlCommand(Master, $@"ALTER DATABASE [{_DatabaseName}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;EXEC sp_detach_db '{_DatabaseName}', 'true'");
                fileNames.ForEach(File.Delete);
            }

            if (File.Exists(Filename))
                File.Delete(Filename);

            if (File.Exists(LogFilename))
                File.Delete(LogFilename);
        }

        private void CreateEmptyDatabaseAndSeedData()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (!_databaseInitialized)
                {
                    using (var context = CreateContext())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DestroyDatabaseRawSQL();
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }

                        try
                        {
                            CreateDatabaseRawSQL();
                            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }

                        if (ShouldSeedActualData)
                        {
                            List<UserDB> entities = new List<UserDB>()
                            {
                                new UserDB() { Id = "Admin@sample.com", Name= "Admin" }
                            };

                            context.Users.AddRange(entities);
                            context.SaveChanges();

                            List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>()
                            {
                                new IdentityRole(){Id = "ADMIN",Name = nameof(DefaultRoles.Admin), NormalizedName = nameof(DefaultRoles.Admin)},
                                new IdentityRole(){Id = "FINANCE",Name = nameof(DefaultRoles.Finance), NormalizedName = nameof(DefaultRoles.Finance)}
                            };

                            context.Roles.AddRange(roles);
                            context.SaveChanges();

                        }
                    }

                    _databaseInitialized = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Connection.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Then, test class looks like following (for simplicity showing just 2 tests):

```
public class BaseRepositoryTests : IClassFixture<SharedDatabaseFixture>
{
        private readonly SharedDatabaseFixture fixture;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public BaseRepositoryTests(SharedDatabaseFixture fixture)
        {
            this.fixture = fixture;

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
            {
                opts.AddProfile<CountriesDBMapper>();
                opts.AddProfile<EmployeeDBMapper>();
                opts.AddProfile<EmployeeAccountDBMapper>();
            });

            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task EntityCannotBeSavedIfDbEntityIsNotValid()
        {
            using (var transaction = fixture.Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var context = fixture.CreateContext(transaction))
                {
                    var baseCountryRepository = new BaseRepository<CountryDB, Country>(context, _mapper);
                    var invalidCountry = new Country() { };

                    //Act
                    var exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<DbUpdateException>(async () => await baseCountryRepository.CreateAsync(invalidCountry));
                    Assert.NotNull(exception.InnerException);
                    Assert.Contains("Cannot insert the value NULL into column", exception.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task EntityCanBeSavedIfEntityIsValid()
        {
            using (var transaction = fixture.Connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var context = fixture.CreateContext(transaction))
                {
                    var baseCountryRepository = new BaseRepository<CountryDB, Country>(context, _mapper);
                    var item = new Country() { Code = "SK", Name = "Slovakia" };

                    //Act
                    var result = await baseCountryRepository.CreateAsync(item);
                    Assert.NotNull(result);
                    Assert.Equal(1, result.Id);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Finally here is a sample of repository implementation (CRUD):

```
  public async Task<TModel> CreateAsync(TModel data)
    {
        var newItem = mapper.Map<Tdb>(data);

        var entity = await context.Set<Tdb>().AddAsync(newItem);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return mapper.Map<TModel>(entity.Entity);
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(long id)
    {
        var item = await context.Set<Tdb>().FindAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var result = context.Set<Tdb>().Remove(item);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); 

        return (result.State == EntityState.Deleted || result.State == EntityState.Detached);
    }
```

If I run these tests individually, each one of them passes without a problem. However if I run all tests from `BaseRepositoryTests` then I am getting random problems as somehow, database transactions are not rolled back but the data is saved and shared between tests.

I have checked and truly, each transaction has it's own unique ID, thus they should not collide. Am I missing anything here? I mean according to Microsoft this is correct approach, but there is clearly something I have missed. The only thing different from other guides that I could find is, that I am using `SaveChangesAsync` in my repository implementation, while other's use `SaveChanges`...however I believe that this should not be the root cause of my problem.

Any help in respect to this matter would be highly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

As suggested by comments, I have tried two separate approaches. First one was to use `CommitableTransaction` like following:

Method update:

```
[Fact]
public async Task EntityCanBeSavedIfEntityIsValid()
{
    using (var transaction = new CommittableTransaction(new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
    {
        using (var context = fixture.CreateContext(transaction))
        {
            var baseCountryRepository = new BaseRepository<CountryDB, Country>(context, _mapper);
            var item = new Country() { Code = "SK", Name = "Slovakia" };

            //Act
            var result = await baseCountryRepository.CreateAsync(item);
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(1, result.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Shared fixture update:

```
public ApplicationDbContext CreateContext(CommittableTransaction transaction = null)
{
    ... other code

    if (transaction != null)
    {
        context.Database.EnlistTransaction(transaction);
    }
   
    return context;
}
```

This unfortunately ended with the same result when running my code tests in bulk (data that I was saving ended up being incremented and not discarded after each test)

Second thing I tried was using `TransactionScope` like following:

```
[Fact]
public async Task EntityCanBeModifiedIfEntityExistsAndIsValid()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        using (var context = fixture.CreateContext())
        {
            var baseCountryRepository = new BaseRepository<CountryDB, Country>(context, _mapper);
            var item = new Country() { Code = "SK", Name = "Slovakia" };

            //Act
            var insertResult = await baseCountryRepository.CreateAsync(item);
            Assert.NotNull(insertResult);
            Assert.Equal(1, insertResult.Id);
            Assert.Equal("SK", insertResult.Code);
            Assert.Equal("Slovakia", insertResult.Name);

            //Act
            insertResult.Code = "SVK";

            var result = await baseCountryRepository.UpdateAsync(insertResult.Id, insertResult);
            Assert.Equal(1, result.Id);
            Assert.Equal("SVK", result.Code);
            Assert.Equal("Slovakia", result.Name);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Just as before this did not yield any new results.

Last thing that I tried was to drop `:IClassFixture<SharedDatabaseFixture>` from the test class and instead, create a new instance of my database fixture in constructor (which is being triggered for each test run) like following:

```
public BaseRepositoryTests()
{
    this.fixture = new SharedDatabaseFixture();
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
    {
        opts.AddProfile<CountriesDBMapper>();
        opts.AddProfile<EmployeeDBMapper>();
        opts.AddProfile<EmployeeAccountDBMapper>();
    });

    _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
}
```

Just as before, no new results came from this update.

**Working setup**

Shared database fixture (basically class responsible for creating database...the main difference between previous version now is, that in constructor it accepts unique guid that is used when creating database -> to create a database with unique name. Furthermore I have also added a new method `ForceDestroyDatabase()` which is responsible to destroy the database after test has done it's job. I did not place it in `Dispose()` method, as sometimes you want to check what actually happened to database, where in that case you just don't call the method...see later)

```
public class SharedDatabaseFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();
        private static bool _databaseInitialized;
        private string _DatabaseName = "FercamPortal.Server.Local.";
        private static IConfigurationRoot config;
        public SharedDatabaseFixture(string guid)
        {
            config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
               .Build();

            var test = config.GetValue<string>("DataSource");

            this._DatabaseName += guid;

            var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = config.GetValue<string>("DataSource"),
                InitialCatalog = _DatabaseName,
                IntegratedSecurity = true,
            };
            var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            CreateEmptyDatabaseAndSeedData();
            Connection.Open();
        }
         ...other code the same as above, skipped for clarity

private void CreateEmptyDatabaseAndSeedData()
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    using (var context = CreateContext())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DestroyDatabaseRawSQL();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { }
    
                        try
                        {
                            CreateDatabaseRawSQL();
                            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                        }
    
                        catch (Exception) { }
    
                        if (ShouldSeedActualData)
                        {
                            List<UserDB> entities = new List<UserDB>()
                                {
                                    new UserDB() { Id = "Robert_Jokl@swissre.com", Name= "Robert Moq" },
                                    new UserDB() { Id = "Test_User@swissre.com", Name= "Test User" }
                                };
    
                            context.Users.AddRange(entities);
                            context.SaveChanges();
    
                            List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>()
                                {
                                    new IdentityRole(){Id = "ADMIN",Name = nameof(FercamDefaultRoles.Admin), NormalizedName = nameof(FercamDefaultRoles.Admin)},
                                    new IdentityRole(){Id = "FINANCE",Name = nameof(FercamDefaultRoles.Finance), NormalizedName = nameof(FercamDefaultRoles.Finance)}
                                };
    
                            context.Roles.AddRange(roles);
                            context.SaveChanges();
    
                        }
                    }
    
                }
            }

        
        public void ForceDestroyDatabase()
        {
            DestroyDatabaseRawSQL();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Connection.Close();
            Connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Sample test class:

```
public class DailyTransitDBRepositoryTests : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SharedDatabaseFixture fixture;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        private IMapper _mapper;

        public DailyTransitDBRepositoryTests()
        {
            this.fixture = new SharedDatabaseFixture(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
            this.context = this.fixture.CreateContext();
            this.context.Database.OpenConnection();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
            {
                opts.AddProfile<DailyTransitDBMapper>();
                opts.AddProfile<EmployeeDBMapper>();
                opts.AddProfile<EmployeeAccountDBMapper>();
                opts.AddProfile<CountriesDBMapper>();
            });

            _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }


        ...other code ommited for clarity

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.context.Database.CloseConnection();
            this.context.Dispose();

            this.fixture.ForceDestroyDatabase();
            this.fixture.Dispose();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetTransitsForYearAndMonthOnlyReturnsValidItems()
        {
            var employees = await PopulateEmployeesAndReturnThemAsList(context);
            var countries = await PopulateCountriesAndReturnThemAsList(context);

            var transitRepository = new DailyTransitDBRepository(context, _mapper);

            var transitItems = new List<DailyTransit>() {
                    new DailyTransit()
                    {
                        Country = countries.First(),
                        Employee = employees.First(),
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        TransitionDurationType = DailyTransitDurationEnum.FullDay
                    },
                    new DailyTransit()
                    {
                        Country = countries.First(),
                        Employee = employees.Last(),
                        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                        TransitionDurationType = DailyTransitDurationEnum.FullDay
                    },
                    new DailyTransit()
                    {
                        Country = countries.First(),
                        Employee = employees.Last(),
                        Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                        TransitionDurationType = DailyTransitDurationEnum.FullDay
                    }
                    };

            //Act
            await transitRepository.CreateRangeAsync(transitItems);

            //retrieve all items
            using (var context2 = fixture.CreateContext())
            {
                var transitRepository2 = new DailyTransitDBRepository(context2, _mapper);
                var items = await transitRepository2.GetEmployeeTransitsForYearAndMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

                Assert.Equal(2, items.Count());
                Assert.Equal("Janko", items.First().Employee.Name);
                Assert.Equal("John", items.Last().Employee.Name);
            }
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: As a point of clarification, by definition, if you are testing anything outside of your immediate class, it is an integration test, not a unit test, especially in cases where you are dealing with external dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated title to call it integration test

Comment: I'm a bit stunned to see that the link you refer to suggests to start a transaction in each individual test. You should do that in a shared test setup method (I'm sure XUnit will have such a concept) and roll it back in a shared test tear-down. But then you should use TransactionScope with async flow because the connection won't be available in those methods.

Comment: Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267046/861716) for some old ramblings on this area.

Comment: I have refactored the code to use `Transaction Scope` and also `CommitableTransaction` (see code edits) but unfortunately none of the methods worked. Once again, individually these methods ran perfectly fine, but when I ran all tests from class at once, it failed as they were somehow using same context.

Comment: You should roll back the TransactionScope, which happens by not calling `Complete()`. Also, don't use the same repository object for the act and assert phase.

Comment: I tried both with Complete() and without Complete() but result was the same. Thank you for noticing that, I have fixed my references in code as well

Comment: Oh boy, Did I suffer this ***** issue. Just for the sake of simplicity, please do consider not sharing the database context using the ```IClassFixture``` it is not mature enough yet, or am I too dumb to do it right. You could instead give it a try to this simple approach => https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845859/9667085

Comment: @RodRamírez Well, a context per test class isn't what you want. Context per test should be OK.

Comment: @RodRamírez kindly make this as an answer as your link gave me an idea to refactor my code in a way which worked.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include answer at the very end of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert, Glad It helped! As per your request, [I re-submit the answer for anyone that could find this answer helpful as you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64800148/how-to-parametrize-a-xunit-class-fixture/64845859#64845859)

I learn the hard way that trying to share the entity framework database context over `IClassFixture` or `CollectionFixtures` would eventually end up in tests being polluted with another test data or deadlock/race conditions due to the parallel execution of xUnit, entity framework throwing exceptions because it already tracked that object with a given Id and more headaches like that.
Personally, I would kindly recommend that for your specific use cause, stick the database context creation/cleanup within the `constructor/dispose` alternative such as:

```cs
    public class TestClass : IDisposable
    {
        DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;

        public TestClass()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>()
              .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
              .Options;

            DatabaseContext = new DatabaseContext(options);

            //insert the data that you want to be seeded for each test method:
            DatabaseContext.Set<Product>().Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
            DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FirstTest()
        {
            var product = DatabaseContext.Set<Product>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).Name;
            //product evaluates to => 0f25a10b-1dfd-4b4b-a69d-4ec587fb465b
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SecondTest()
        {
            var product = DatabaseContext.Set<Product>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).Name;
            //product evaluates to => eb43d382-40a5-45d2-8da9-236d49b68c7a
            //It's different from firstTest because is another object
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            DatabaseContext.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Of course you can always do some refinement, but the idea is there