# Entity framework 6 with Autofac unit testing DataContext

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-6, autofac

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with Autofac for Dependency injection.

Here is my database context wrapper code:

```
public interface IOliveDataContext
{
    OlivesHealthEntities Context { get; }
}
```

Here is its implementation:

```
public class OliveDataContext : IOliveDataContext
{
    public OlivesHealthEntities Context => new OlivesHealthEntities();
}
```

I wonder if there is anyway to wrap the default context with in-memory database connection for unit testing or I have to connect to an other database to do the test.

Can anyone help me please ?

P/s : I've read some tuts about unit testing with EF6, they always write context interfaces for this, its different from my current app implementation.

Comment: You might find it easier to [mock the DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx), which would allow you to customise behaviour and assert conditions. If you wish to perform integration testing, then you can [set up your database in a controlled manner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22691703/1269511) to allow you to test your mapping logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about in-memory database instance, there is [Effort](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1036630/using-effort-entity-framework-unit-testing-tool) for that purpose. It simulate real database using entity framework engine on memory.
It has limitation though, it couldn't simulate stored procedure, view, and trigger.