# EF InMemory database

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a tool for Entity Framework In Memory database (for unit testing purposes) for standard .NET Framework?

I know there is one for .NET Core that works great, but for this project I need for the standard.NET framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are people unit testing with Entity Framework 6, should you bother?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690877/how-are-people-unit-testing-with-entity-framework-6-should-you-bother)

Comment: Please read [ask], [help/on-topic] and share your research. Directly asking for tools is off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: Do you mean for EF6?

Comment: Yes, Effort.EF6 works great in my case, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Effort](https://github.com/tamasflamich/effort) might be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, very easy to work with, exactly what I was searching for, thank you